# How to parse Stylus error message output

Tags: regex, stylus

I'm trying to parse a error message produced by the [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/) binary, for instance this example error from the [documentation](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/error-reporting.html):

```
  ParseError: test.styl:3:16
    1| body
    2|    form input
    3|      == padding 5px
  ---------------------^
    4|


  illegal unary "==", missing left-hand operand
```

I'm basically after getting the file-name, line and column, as well as the error message at the end. Since there seems to be no option to control the verbosity of the output, I need to ignore all lines that start with whitespace (followed by a digit) or dashes.

Here is what I currently have: `.*Error: (.+):(\d+):(\d+)\n(?:\W+.*\n)+(.*\n)`

While this might not be the ideal pattern, the real trouble is that stylus might output several additional lines which breaks the pattern.

```
illegal unary "==", missing left-hand operand

    at Parser.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:259:11)
    at Parser.equality (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:1905:23)
    at Parser.typecheck (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:1886:21)
    at Parser.logical (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:1873:21)
    at Parser.ternary (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:1857:21)
    at Parser.negation (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:1849:17)
    at Parser.expression (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:1828:24)
    at Parser.stmt (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:818:25)
    at Parser.statement (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:685:21)
    at Parser.block (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:865:21)
```

The pattern above will correctly capture the file-name, line and column, but always use the last-line from the error log – rather than the error message I'm after.

How can I reliably capture the error message?

Comment: In the first code block, every line starts with more than one whitespace, except for the dashed line, which has exactly one. Is that true for all output?

Comment: Yes, but unless the error appears on the last line, there might be more lines after the dashed line that follow the pattern of the one before the dashed line.

Comment: In this case you can just match line-breaks, which I have done in the answer below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37996266/2491198

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking advantage of this specific output structure, you could make use of the **single newlines** coming after the numbered code lines: `(?:\n)+`

Then you have:

```
((.*Error): (.+):(\d+):(\d+))\n(?:\ +.*\n)+(?:\n)+(.*)
```

#### Explanation:

```
# First line with matching error, file name, line, column
((.*Error): (.+):(\d+):(\d+))\n   

# Non-matching group for lines starting with whitespace and multiple characters after
(?:\ +.*\n)+                      

# Non-matching group for at least one newline
(?:\n)+                           

# Lastly, match single line at the end
(.*)
```

**Example:** https://regex101.com/r/uQ7dM5/1